Deploying assemblies with local function of logic app standard
I've followed this blog post to create an Azure logic app standard with a dotnet 8 local function. The local function needs to reference an app setting of the logic app, so I make use of IConfiguration, as shown below:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

    public class SvcBusQReader
    {
        private readonly ILogger<SvcBusQReader> _logger;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public SvcBusQReader(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SvcBusQReader>();
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [Function("ReadQueueSessionMessage")]
        public async Task<string> Run([WorkflowActionTrigger]
            string queueName, string sessionId)
        {
            var serviceBusNamespace = _configuration["Values:serviceBus_fullyQualifiedNamespace"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(serviceBusNamespace))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Service Bus namespace is not configured.");
            }

            // Use DefaultAzureCredential to authenticate using Managed Identity
            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
            var client = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusNamespace, credential);

            var receiver = await client.AcceptSessionAsync(queueName, sessionId);
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message = await receiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();
            string messageBody = message.Body.ToString();
            return messageBody;
        }
    }

In order to ensure the referenced "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll" and other dependencies are deployed with the logic app, I made the following additions to the csproj file of the local function:
<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
<Copy SourceFiles="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" DestinationFolder="..\$(LogicAppFolder)\lib\custom\net8\" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />

After deployment, I open a kudu session and can see all of the referenced Microsoft assemblies alongside my SvcBusQReader.AzFunc.dll in the folder "C:\home\site\wwwroot\lib\custom".
However, when the logic app workflow is run and the the local function is called, I see the following exception in app insights:
"Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."
I've since tried removing the dependency on IConfiguration but then it threw an error Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus could not be found. This applies both deployed to azure and when debugging locally. I suspect that calls to "external" assemblies from the local function aren't supported but I'm not sure, and if so why the limitation is in place? Also, it's strange that no such limitation exists for .Net Framework (.472) local functions.
